# Does type create the class 'Object' in python

Tags: python, metaclass

I was reading about this excellent post on metaclasses [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). The accepted answer shows how to create a class using `type` with the following signature.

```
type(name of the class, 
      tuple of the parent class (for inheritance, can be empty), 
      dictionary containing attributes names and values)
```

That makes me wonder who creates the object class. Is object class also created by `type` class?

Comment: pssst, Karthick: join http://bostonpython.com , if you haven't already...

Comment: @NedBatchelder Sure. I just did! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory you are correct. `object` is an instance of `type`. But, when you check `type`'s base classes, you'll find that `type` inherits from `object`! How can this be?

The truth is, this is hard-coded in the Python interpreter. Both `object` and `type` are given; neither is actually involved in any way with creating the other.

Comment: Exactly.. type inherits from object and object is instantiated by type.. How is this possible and hence this question!

Comment: @Jon: `type.__mro__ == (<type 'type'>, <type 'object'>)`. Also `issubclass(type, object) == True`.

Comment: What version Python are we using here?

Comment: Got the above results in both Python 2.6.6 and 3.1.2.

Answer (score 3):

The main thing to remember at these rarified levels of the object/type hierarchy is that things like `object` and `type` are not created in .py files at all, they are created statically in C code, along with the rest of the foundational underpinnings of CPython.  So they aren't necessarily "created" with any particular Python code.

Answer (score 0):

`type` is a bit of a - umm, not sure how to describe it - *weirdo* of the language.

It can be used to do type(someobj) or used as a constructor (with 3 params) of some sorts to create new types derived from a base with instances. As you have seen with meta-classes - it's useful to make factory classes - although, IMHO unless you really want to be too clever, using class decorators makes this slightly easier in 2.6+